# Python importlib fails to import a module when run from shell

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I am using `line_profiler` module to line-by-line profile my python code. At some point in the code, I use `importlib.import_module` command, and it fails while all the other imports function fine. If I run the line in PyCharm and not in the shell, everything works fine.

This is the file structure:

```
../
  core/
    __init__.py
    battery_meta.py
    battery_models.py
  models/
    __init__.py
    battery_model_07.py
  kernprof.py
```

I am running a command:

```
python kernprof.py -l core/battery_models.py -v
```

And the following line in `battery_meta.py`

```
module = importlib.import_module('battery_model_07', 'models')
```

results in an error:

```
ImportError: No module named battery_model_07
```

I have tried so far:

1. Adding the project directory to the path directly before the import, like this: `sys.path.append(<project_path>)`
2. Adding `__init__.py` file in the project directory

Both with no result... again, all the other imports work fine. 
Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong and how to fix it?